# Hacked Wordpress account

Tags: wordpress, passwords, md5

Good evening to everybody,
I've found some problems managing a Wordpress website which has been hacked some hours ago. 
I've changed all the password and created new users for db and domain panel, for wp admin panel too. However, even if I've changed the passwords I've seen that the MD5 hash I've modified to change to another password, the password hash returns continuously to the the hash of the people who hacked the website. It's like they were "monitoring" the website domain panel, recording the changes and trying to change it again.

Anyway the website is online now.

Anyone can help to stop them and avoid other attacks of this kind ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've been hacked, you should consider the whole machine as compromised. Re-install everything (including the OS if you can) and restore only the data, and manually to make sure you don't restore a compromised account or something like that.

Comment: Thank you 1ace, the website is hosted on an external server. Do you think they can help me in this ?

Comment: You should contact their support, only they can answer that.
They probably use virtual machines, so they can just overwrite the disk image.

Comment: Thank you for your effort ;)